# Why on double click android client received data?

Tags: java, android, sockets

When I click the first time on login button, data send to server and server received data in return on first click data not show on android client screen. When I pressed login button again it again send data and then it show data on client screen... plz help me. Why data is received on secind click i want my data recived on my first click?
Here is the code :

Client **tcpip** code...

```
    public class SockProg {

    private Socket socket;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    DataInputStream dataInputStream;
    String data;
    String serverip = "192.168.1.7";
    int serverport = 4444;



    public void connetToServer(){
        try {
            socket = new Socket(serverip, serverport);
            Log.i("AsyncTank", "doInBackgoung: Created Socket");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (socket.isConnected()) {
            try {
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                        socket.getOutputStream());
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    public void writeToStream(String message) {
         try {
             if (socket.isConnected()){
                 dataOutputStream.writeUTF(message.toString());
            } else {
                Log.i("AsynkTask", "writeToStream : Cannot write to stream, Socket is closed");
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("AsynkTask", "writeToStream : Writing failed");
           }  
    }
    public String readFromStream() {
         String ret = null;
        try {
            if (socket.isConnected()) {
                Log.i("AsynkTask", "readFromStream : Reading message");
                 ret=dataInputStream.readUTF();
                Log.i("AsynkTask", "readFromStream : read "+ret);

            } else {
                Log.i("AsynkTask", "readFromStream : Cannot Read, Socket is closed");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("AsynkTask", "readFromStream : Reading failed"+e.getClass());
        }
        return ret;
        }
    public void CloseSockets(){
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (dataOutputStream != null) {
            try {
                dataOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (dataInputStream != null) {
            try {
                dataInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is the code of **sychronized thread**

```
    public class TCP implements Runnable {


    String data;
    SockProg sp;
    Thread thh;
    private static String rdata;

    public TCP(SockProg spr, String val) {
        sp = spr;
        data = val;
        thh = new Thread(this);
        thh.start();
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(sp) { // synchronized block
            //rdata= sp.DataSendRecive(data);
            sp.connetToServer();
            sp.writeToStream(data);
            rdata=sp.readFromStream();
            sp.CloseSockets();
          }
    }
    public static String getData(){
        return rdata;
    }


}
```

here is code of **Login** Activity...

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg_log);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // try{

                txtph = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_phnum);
                txtpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_pass);
                ph = txtph.getText().toString();
                pass = txtpass.getText().toString();

                int ch = 0;

                if (ph.equals("") || ph == null) {
                    msg.setText("Please Enter Mobile Number....\n");
                    ch++;
                }
                if (pass.equals("") || pass == null) {
                    if (ch == 0) {
                        msg.setText("Please Enter your Password....\n");
                    } else {
                        msg.append("Please Enter your Password....\n");
                    }

                    ch++;
                }
                if (ch == 0) {

                    ArrayList<String> ph_pass = new ArrayList<String>();
                    ph_pass.add(0, "LoginAccount");
                    ph_pass.add(1, ph);
                    ph_pass.add(2, pass);
                    SockProg sp=new SockProg();
                    TCP t=new TCP(sp, ph_pass.toString());
                    data=t.getData();
                    msg.setText(data);


                }
            }

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a classic case of asynchronous coding delay. The TCP class is a runnable and therefor when it is called the first time (the first click on the login button) it starts running,  but the Thread does not have enough time to finish

```
rdata=sp.readFromStream();
```

in the run() method, therefor `data=t.getData();` does not return anything useful. The second click, provides the runnable with enough time populate the rdata with some data and therefor your program works.

When working with asynchrounous code, you need a better way to wait for code to complete what it is doing.

Why is rdata a static type? Make it non-static and then change the getData() method like this:

```
public synchronized String getData()
```

Comment: i understand what you said... but on my first click i want my data recived which is send by server.. is there any changes you suggest me in this code??

Comment: yes, read the last line of my post, and make rdata non static, and make the getData method synchronized

Comment: i did it what you said but the result was same ...:(